# Only assignment call increment decrement and new object expression can be use as statement error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I wanted to check my last element's array lenght is 6 or not.In here i don't know how many id's comes with this array. My message array comes like this.

> Code Username id1 id2 id3... date

```
    if ([msg_arr.Length - 1] == 6)//YYMMDD  
    {
        strDate = msg_arr[msg_arr.Length - 1].ToString();
    }
```

But i'm getting error here.

> Only assignment,call,increment,decrement and new object expression can be use as statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be `if (msg_arr[msg_arr.Length - 1].Length == 6)`.

Comment: if i do this then comes this error.. Cannot Apply Operator == to operands of type 'string &' int

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad -- but if `msg_arr` is an array of strings, the `ToString()` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ([msg_arr.Length - 1] == 6) //this is a problem
```

You didn't specify the data you access to, I **presume** it has to be something like

```
if (msg_arr[msg_arr.Length - 1] == 6)
```

**If** content of he array is `string`, ca do the following:

- or

  int val = int.Parse(msg_arr[msg_arr.Length - 1]);

  if (val == 6)
- or

  if (msg_arr[msg_arr.Length - 1] == "6")

Comment: if i do this then comes this error.. Cannot Apply Operator == to operands of type 'string &' int

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're expecting a string date in the format YYMMDD, and you want to be sure that you have six values in the array.
I believe what you wish this:

```
if (msg_arr.Length == 6)//YYMMDD  
{
    strDate = (String.Join("", msg_arr);
}
```

The ToString() method would only assign the string name of the object, so strDate would have a value of something like "System.Int32[]"